# Did Lee Harvey Oswald receive any medals or ribbons?

Tags: military

Did Lee Harvey Oswald, in his time as a marine, receive any medals or ribbons? I don't expect any significant decorations (other than sharpshooter). I know he worked as a metalworker (both in Texas and the USSR). I know that he shot at people who had multiple decorations (other than Kenedy). I just don't know where to look to see if he got a good conduct medal or a campaign ribbon.

Comment: Curious as to why this has been down-voted? Sure, it could do with a bit of editing and formatting, but it looks to me like a valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His [USMC service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Harvey_Oswald#Marine_Corps) was October 24th 1956 to September 11th, 1959. He was trained as a radar operator, and served in that role in Japan.

The Marine Corps Good Conduct Medal required three consecutive years of good conduct at the time. He would not have had it: he did not serve for three years, and while he was quite bright and fairly capable, he wasn't good at long-term discipline, and was court-martialled twice, and punished on a third occasion.

If he had any awards for personal bravery or achievement, they'd be in his biography, so we're left with campaign and qualification types of award.

Going through the lists of [US military](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awards_and_decorations_of_the_United_States_Armed_Forces) awards for ones he might have been eligible for, I'm not finding anything:

## Current Awards

- He didn't serve long enough in the reserves to be eligible for anything.
- Eligibility for the Navy Occupation Service Medal had ended in 1952.
- The National Defense Service Medal wasn't being awarded at the time, because there wasn't a war on. None of the other general service or special service medals were in existence at the time.
- Oswald wasn't eligible for any of the current campaign medals, or any of the service and training awards, most of which were created after his death.

## Obsolete Awards

He doesn't seem to have been eligible for any of these. Nor for any of the recognised foreign decorations.

Oswald's Sharpshooter badge seems to have been all he earned.